# PHP echo code not returning '0' if no results

Tags: php

Here is the query:

```
$query = "SELECT name,deleted,COUNT(message) as message FROM guestbook_message WHERE name='".$name."' AND deleted=1 GROUP BY name";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$deletedtotal_row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Here when I use it:

```
echo "You have had ".($deletedtotal_row['deleted']) ? $deletedtotal_row['deleted'] : '0'." messages deleted";
```

This errors, doesn't show an syntax error, but doesn't display any results.

But when I use:

```
echo ".$totaldeleted_row['deleted'].";
```

It works fine. But if there is no messages deleted for that user, it returns nothing, but I want it to display '0'.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "You have had ".intval($deletedtotal_row['deleted'])." messages deleted";
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this, but we do not have to correct typo's but suggest better code.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
echo "You have had ".($deletedtotal_row['deleted'] ? $deletedtotal_row['deleted'] : '0')." messages deleted";
```

Also, this `echo ".$totaldeleted_row['deleted'].";` is very bad. Do this instead:

```
echo $totaldeleted_row['deleted'];
```

Comment: It's not *very bad*.  It may not be optimal.  It may not be great to read.  But it's by no means *very bad* (especially related to your alternative)...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is using name=".$name." ok to use in the query?

Comment: It seems to throw all my divs out of sync when I use that. It's fine until I try to display the '0' result. The divs are also inside the php.

Comment: @Tom, Depends where `$name` is coming from. If it's correct sanitized then yes. But you should really be using prepared statements rather than plain old xml. Look at the mysqli or pdo libraries. They're packaged with PHP 5.

Comment: @ircmaxell, my _alternative_ is the correct an only syntax that wont return _any_ kind of error/notice/warning. For this to be anywhere near correct usage it would have to be `"{$totaldeleted_row['deleted']}"`. As it is it would output _.x._ and return a warning or notice I believe.

Comment: @Tom, I couldn't imagine why unless there is another error in your code causing unmatched div. Best to run the outputted html through a html validator to find any unmatched tags.

Comment: @xzyfer: That has nothing to do with notices or warnings.  If `".$totaldeleted_row['deleted']."` raises an error, `echo $total...` would as well.  `"{$total...}"` is another valid usage, but that doesn't make concatenation wrong...

Comment: @ircmaxell, what are you talking about? `echo ".$totaldeleted_row['deleted']."` isn't concatenating anything. And causes a fatal error: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING". Where as `echo $totaldeleted_row['deleted']` echoes the value correctly. The only way the first example concatenates or is even valid is with something like this `echo "hello ".$totaldeleted_row['deleted']." world"`

Comment: @xzyfer: I meant that it was the sub-part of the original string `echo "You have had ".$deltedtotal_row["deleted"]." blah"`.  I only used the short part since there are limited characters here, and limited formatting.  So to keep readability and conciseness, I did it this way...

Comment: @ircmaxell, that would have made sense, but he wrote `echo ".$totaldeleted_row['deleted']."` in the question, ver batem. Given that context it made no sense hence my reply _is very bad_. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
   echo 'no rows';
} else {
   echo "You have had " . $deletedtotal_row['deleted'] ." messages deleted";
}
```

Comment: You can just set a var and then use that in your echo - but I think using intval() is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I got it working with:

```
echo "You have had ".($deletedtotal_row['deleted'] ? $deletedtotal_row['deleted'] : '0')." messages deleted";
```

Comment: If you use someone's answer you should acknowledge it by accepting their answer. It helps your acceptance rating, which inturn makes people more inclined to help you. It's also the foundation of the stack exchange network.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
sprintf("You have had %d messages deleted", $deletedtotal_row['deleted');
```